# Tab and Enter key do not work anymore in the webstorm editor while typing

Tags: webstorm

Ever since I upgraded my webstorm IDE to v8.0.4 the enter/return and tab key has no effect in the code editor.

Could there maybe any settings I have somehow changed that these keys does not work?

I have just found out that this odd behavior is only in the main index.html file not in my partial html files ???!!!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I had the same problem in one particular project, and other keystrokes also didn't work, including "(".

Selecting File > Invalidate Caches / Restart fixed it.

Comment: Yes and it was only in a certain project here too!

Comment: Sorry to complain but that error is a shame. Being a powerfull editor with a lot of functionality should not be a priority. The priority is to actually to edit the damn file as it should....

Answer (score 9):

For me it wasn't invalidating caches or removing plugins. There is actually an "editor action" in the keymap settings called "Enter". Apparently I removed the key (enter) mapped to that by accident.

Answer (score 5):

Just experienced the same issue but clearing the Invalidate Cache wasn't working for me.

I found that I had downloaded "Bootstrap 3 live templates/ snippets" plugin just prior. This for some reason rendered by editor unable to take enter/return keys as well as the tab key.

After removing the plugin the editor went back to working normally. I would suggest going over recently downloaded plugins and seeing if one of them might be causing the issues.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else struggling to figure out why this is happening, this happened to me on my MacBook pro due to having the `ABC` Keyboard configured in System Preferences > Keyboard instead of `ABC Extended`

Answer (score 1):

In my case, Enabling ECMAScript 6 was the problem, I simply choose ECMAScript 5.1 again and everything now is working as it should!

change it from `File->Settings->Languages & Frameworks->JavaScript` and change the JavaScript language version to ECMAScript 5.1

Still very weird bug though

Answer (score 1):

you have to map "Enter" to "Enter"!

1. setting > keymap >
2. search for enter
3. in "Editor Actions" right click on Enter and select Add key shortcut
4. press enter key
5. press ok and exit settings.

Answer (score 1):

In the latest version of Tabnine on WebStorm or PhpStorm:

Find the keymap "Accept Inline Completion" and remove Tab
[image: Tabnine -> Accept Inline Completion]

Answer (score 0):

Invalidate Cache didnt work for me as well. To be precise, the issue is related to newly added plugin. Fixed this issue by removing the plugin that is added recently.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It is a, plugin issue. The quickest solution is, after starting Webstorm, press the return key. The PluginException will appear in the bottom of the IDE. Click it and you will see the 'disable' option for that specific plugin.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me.  I had to check the Event Log which gave me the option to disable the plugin.